# Ionic 3 - how to open urls (hrefs) of rich text content

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 chat application. In the chat messages users would like to place links (urls) to external resources.

Is there any opportunitiy to make this urls clickable (for chat message receivers) for opening that external resources?

**Example:**

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Install InAppBrowserPlugin -- [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

then on url call make your logic ... eg:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }

...

const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');
 browser.show();
 // browser.close()
```

Comment: I know this plugin, but the challenge lies in the rich text content with the dynamic links. How I can grap, pharse and rewrite (window.open) this links?  Or any other idea?

Comment: i think this may help -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links